# Как навесить событие на один из сабмитов в форме?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма с 2 сабмитами, необходимо отслеживать поле #field_1 и после запустить клик по кнопке #submit_1. Накатал быстро на jQuery - но срабатывает, - подскажите где ошибка ?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#field_1').change(function(){
    $('#myform input[name="submit_1"]').click();
    /*
    $('#myform input[name="submit_1"]').submit();
    $('#myform input[name="submit_1"]').trigger('click');
    $('#myform input[name="submit_1"]').trigger('submit');
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="myform">
      
      <div class="fields">
        <input type="text" id="field_1">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" value="1" id="submit_1" name="submit_1">
      <input type="submit" value="2" id="submit_2" name="submit_2">
      
    </form>
```

Comment: .trigger('click'); - должно работать. Дайте пожалуйста код события клика или субмита

Comment: Пример кода отработал, change срабатывает когда фокус уходит с инпута, я ввел данные, нажал на пустое место и js отработал.

Comment: Что бы вы хотели сделать конкретно? Может мы могли бы подсказать вам более правильный способ.